# Change dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari-extension

I'm building browser plugin (safari extension) that automatically changes an element (by "prepend").
It can be done by calling prepend like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").prepend("<img ...>").
})
```

But, how can I change elements that are created dynamically using javascript?

Comment: `dynamically` can you plz explain about it.

Comment: You can store the DOM element in a local variable. Then you can use it as any other JavaScript object.

Comment: @Jai "dynamically" means, for example, element or html part created by ajax callback.

Comment: So I'm guessing you want your extension to 'listen' to an element being created (on a website that isn't yours)?

Comment: @putvande Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You can 1st create the object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $("<img ...>");
    $("a").prepend(img);
    // do something with img
});
```

Comment: That's not my point of the question, but thank you for your comment. I updated question.

Comment: This is a such weird answer. I don't see any actual answer but the code from the question!

Comment: I may have judged you without thinking. Sorry about that. I can't remove my "vote down" unless you edit the answer again(maybe add a little "update: the OP copied my answer!"), or delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for DOM change:

```
$("body").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
    alert('DOM changed');
});
```

And than figure out what has changed. But that isn't clear from your question what you would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the object you create in a global variable so it is available throughout your webpage... Like so:

```
var img;
$(document).ready(function(){
    img = $("<img ...>");
    $("a").prepend(img).
});
```

Then later on in some other function or something...

```
$(img).click(function() { 
     // blah
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create trigger,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").prepend("<img id="imgId"...>").
        $(document).trigger('asd');
    })
$(document).on('asd', function() {

  });
```

Or you  can create event listner

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("a").prepend("<img id="imgId"...>").

})
$(document).on('click','imgId',function(){

 });
```

Comment: Sorry but "click" or other event is called only when it is "clicked" not when it is created...